# Quick Limit with Series Question

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits

So I was given the following prompt:

"Test the following series for convergence or divergence."

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(\frac{(-2)^{2n}}{n^n})$

I figured that I'd have to use the root test here, but I'm confused about how I'd go about finding the specific limit in this context with the root test. I understand that the limit would look something like the following: $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{(\frac{(-2)^{2n}}{n^n})}$, but I'm confused about how to find that limit. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 1. Note that $2n$ is always even. 2. The root test uses $\sqrt[n]{}$, not the square root.

Comment: $L=lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$
Now, if  $L<1$ the series is absolutely convergent (and hence convergent).
If $L>1$ it diverges.
And it is inconclusive if $L=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made two mistakes:

1. You have to compute the $n$<sup>th</sup> root, not the square root.
2. You have to compute the root of the absolute value.

In your case, you have$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{(-2)^{2n}}{n^n}\right|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac4n=0<1,$$and therefore your series converges.

Comment: Ok I appreciate it, meant to include the $n$th root.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{(-2)^{2n}}{n^n} = \frac{4^n}{n^n} = \left(\frac{4}{n}\right)^n$$